# Jquery click event is not getting fired up

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the js code which does'nt work :

```
$('#change-priority-modal').find('.btn-primary').unbind().on("click", function () { //my_func_body }
```

However the same works with developer console.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is the code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: this is not javascript, it is jquery. And please copy whole line of code. As I can see the code has incomplete closing braces.

Comment: and in what way doesn't it work, exactly? If you're using "on", then you should swap "unbind" for "off". Otherwise it's not the direct opposite equivalent. unbind was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, many years ago and replaced with "off".

Comment: This is impossible to answer unless you provide an example of it not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the click function needed to be in success block of the ajax call of the parent click function. Thanks a tonne for everyone who helped.